# extending a superclass' constructor within a subclass in php

Tags: php, oop, constructor, subclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call parent constructor before child constructor in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079883/call-parent-constructor-before-child-constructor-in-php)

I have a class that manages my database connection. It has a constructor that fetches the database details from a config file:

```
    class Database {
        function __construct(){
        //perform magic
        }
    }
```

I am now extending this class to create a class for managing user creation and validation, and I need it to still do the things the superclass does, but with some extras.

```
class Members {
      function __construct(){
       //perform super class magic
       // then perform your own magic
      }
}
```

What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `parent::__construct`:

```
class Members {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // your code
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to pass any arguments on that the parent class requires.

Comment: Don't forget to use the visibility modifiers.. public, private, or protected.

Comment: hey, my question got you to 10k. You're welcome ;)