# Calling both parent and child constructors

Tags: php, constructor, parent-child

Some of my classes has constructors in both the parent and the child. How can I run both constructors?

Parent class:

```
include 'c:/wamp/www/mvc/include/connect.php';
class Database
{

    protected $mysqli;
    protected $exc;

    function __construct(mysqli $db)
    {
        mysqli_set_charset($db,'utf8');
        $this->mysqli = $db;
    }

<?php
```

Child class: (LoginClass)

```
<?php


class Login extends Database {
    private $username;
    private $password;

    function __construct(mysqli $db, $username, $password)
    {
        parent::__construct($db);
        $this->setData($username, $password);
        $this->getData();
    }
    function setData($username, $password)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }


    function getData()
    {
        $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM anvandare WHERE anvandarnamn = '$this->username;'  AND losenord =  '$this->password'");

        $count = $result->num_rows;

        if($count>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Username or Password incorrect. Please try again");
        }

    }
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php
//LoginController
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit'] == "login")
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        try
        {
            include '../model/Login.php';
            $login = new Login($db ,$username, $password);

            if($login == TRUE)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location:../index.php");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $exc)
        {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling `parent::__construct($this->mysqli);`in the child constructor, but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: What happened when "it didn't work"? An error message?

Comment: It looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079883/call-parent-constructor-before-child-constructor-in-php may provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because the parent constructor requires an instance of `mysqli` to be passed. The following signature should work, though:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Database.php';

class Login extends Database
{
    function __construct(mysqli $db, $username, $password)
    {
        parent::__construct($db);
        $this->setData($username, $password);
        $this->getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in `class Login extends Database`

Comment: @David.J If your `Database` class is defined in another script, you must include that first using `require_once`.

Comment: It works for classes that has no constructors. It's just with the ones that has constructors that doesn't work

Comment: @David.J That makes no sense; the error you have mentioned here is another problem altogether.

Comment: Updated the question. I've added my loginClass and my loginController. I would appreciate it if you could check it out.

Comment: @David.J As I've mentioned earlier, you must include the Database class before declaring the Login class ... I've updated my answer.